# Talend - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The import routines cannot be resolved

Tags: talend

While working on Talend Integration Open Studio v7.3.1 & v7.2.1, I am facing below error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        The import routines cannot be resolved
        The import routines cannot be resolved
        The import routines cannot be resolved
        The import routines cannot be resolved
        TalendJob cannot be resolved to a type
        RunStat cannot be resolved to a type
        RunStat cannot be resolved to a type
        routines cannot be resolved to a type
        LogCatcherUtils cannot be resolved to a type
        LogCatcherUtils cannot be resolved to a type
        TDieException cannot be resolved to a type
...
```

Even though there is no compile error in main job or sub jobs, the main job gives the above error sporadically. In order to overcome this error, I have to restart my Talend Studio and then the error goes away. But restarting studio is a costly affair because it checks for components in background and hangs the open studio for good 10-15 mins. And there is no setting in "open studio" to disable the components check.

Is there any better way to fix this "Unresolved compilation problems" issue?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've had the same issue and was just ready to start "looking in detail" instead of a simple reboot. Unfortunately i didn't have a better solution, just wanted to let you know that this was indeed helpful!

Comment: If you have some subjob, you have to open them and "save as" each.

Answer (score 1):

This Talend Community post worked for me: https://community.talend.com/s/feed/0D53p00007vCkCBCA0?language=en_US
"In the Talend Open Studio, Go to menu File -> Edit Project properties
In project Settings go to:
Build -> Maven -> Default -> Project

And click OK" (or apply and close)